# Display character % with minted

Tags: minted

How can I display the `%` character with minted without it being considered a comment? If I write `\minted{%}` the rest of the line is considered a comment, and if I write `\minted{\%}` minted displays both characters: `\%`
Thanks.

If I use `\mintinline[style=bw]{c}{%}` it is displayed well. However if I use the command that I defined: `\newcommand{\mintbw}[1]{\mintinline[style=bw]{c}{#1}}` and write `\mintbw{%}` the `%` character is considered a comment.

Problem solved! Thanks.

Comment: The `%` character is _supposed_ to turn the rest of the line into comments (in a number of languages), right? Maybe you can provide a larger example, to make it more clear what you mean?

Comment: Writing `\minted{...}` is wrong to begin with.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635870/80949 for an answer on the inline command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `minted` environment, not the `\minted` command, which is 'possible', but will not provide what is requested.

Of course, the correct language must be specified, e.g. `TeX` or `php` (if I am remembering correctly), where `%` is a comment character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{tex}
% This is a TeX comment but is not disregarded because it's inside

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}
Dont use $$ in \LaTeXe!  % It's weird!
\end{document}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]