# Display % with \newcommand{\mintinline{...}}

Tags: beamer, minted, fragile

I don't understand why the two frames below are not treated the same way. The first one correctly displays the `%` symbol, while the second one gives an error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand*{\cinline}[1]{\mintinline{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{A}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \mintinline{c}{x%=2;}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}[fragile]{B}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \cinline{c}{x%=2;}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not use `\verb`, `\mintinline` and similar commands in the argument of another command or in definitions. When the argument of `\cinline` is being read `%` is a comment so the closing `}` is never seen and you will have runaway argument errors

Comment: use `\newmintedinline` to define the command then it will use the special verbatim parsing that `\mintinline` uses.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, thank you, it (partially) does. I managed to solve my problem following your comment (it's actually `\newmintinline` though) and the link you provided. But I think an example may be useful for other people as well.

Comment: oops sorry for the typo.